# LCOV code coverage help- compare from previous runs

Tags: c++, code-coverage, lcov

Is there any way to improve code coverage using lcov or gcov , Like I want to compare code coverage from previous runs?

It is useless to run code coverage for whole codings.I want code coverage for only specific files which is modified.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately, this is a very broad question, and not really suited to Stack Overflow - which prefers specific, technical questions (eg "I ran code X and got error Y"). A more specific question might be specifically about how to compare coverage between runs...

Comment: @TarynEast Thanks for your suggestion. I have completed the operations (code coverage)  successfully.

Comment: Hi Anurag, I am checking for the same thing which you posted.. "I want code coverage for only specific files which is modified." and compare reports with previous one. Can you please share us your findings?

Comment: Hello, I'd also need this information... any idea?
Thanks a lot